# Can I add a custom row to MySQL pivot Query that is another pivot?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a crosstab query, that displays results in such a way

```
      user1 user2 user3 ...etc
date1 val11 val12 val13 ... 
date2 val21 val22 val23 ... 
date3 val31 val32 val33 ... 
...
etc
```

Thing is users have a rank field.

I was wandering if I could insert it like so using MySQL:

```
      user1 user2 user3 ...etc
rank  rank1 rank2 rank3
date1 val11 val12 val13 ... 
date2 val21 val22 val23 ... 
date3 val31 val32 val33 ... 
...
etc
```

The application is a php webapp and the final product is an excel spreadsheet. If it cannot be done through a query I would try and add it on conversion of the query results to the excel.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

THe solution would be to have a rank crosstab query ant date-value crosstab query and have a union of each. All columns have to match though.